# Check if latest npm package version has same major version

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

Say I have an NPM package:

```
current_version="1.2.3";
latest_version=`npm view "$package_name" version`
```

how can I use the semver command line tool to determine if the latest version in npm has the same major version as the current_version? Something like:

```
semver --same-major "$current_version" "$latest_version"
```

?

Basically, what I want to do is install to the most recent version with the same major version.

Another related question - how can I find the most recent version in the NPM registry that has the same *major* semver version as the `current_version`?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [carret range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) like this

```
semver -r "^$current_version" "$latest_version"
```

if the input is valid (the same major number), this command print the version and exit with status code 0

else this will print nothing and exit with code 1

PS: you can check for exit code with `echo $?`